# C library tutorial

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn how to program in C. As C is similar to C++ I don't have any problems learning the basic commands (like `for`, `while`, `do`, variable declaring, preprocessor directives, etc). But I find it hard to understand C's libraries. Does anyone know any tutorials about C libraries with code examples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dennis M. Ritchie, Brian W. Kernighan - "The C programming language".

Comment: Be sure to read the latest edition